# No feedback to user on login failure with Rails 3 + Devise + Jquery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jquery-mobile

As it says in the subject, I'm just finishing up integrating Devise authentication into a Rails 3.1 app with Jquery Mobile.  Most everything here is straight out of the box, no custom code, so there's not a lot I can paste in here to add to the description of the problem.

When a user fails the Sign Up process because of a pre-existing email address, password not long enough, etc., a message is displayed to the user.  It isn't pretty, but it at least works.

However when the user has an existing account and types the wrong password during sign in there is no feedback to the user and the console outputs the error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I've got a pretty strong suspicion that this is happening because Jquery's form submit does not expect or know how to handle a 401 error returning from the server, but I'm not certain where to resolve the issue.

If it matters, I have uncommented the following in the Devise initializer:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
```

I'm also expecting that much of my problem here stems from my lack of understanding about how Rails flash notices are (or are not) integrated in JqueryMobile.  Hopefully an answer here will take me that much further towards figuring it out.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile 'takes over' your form submissions. However, you can simply override this behavior by adding your own form submit listener. If you do that, you should be able to add any custom logic you want.

Comment: Also, if you want to just disable the automatic handling of the form, you can add data-ajax="false" to your form tag.